# Multi module maven project assembling

Tags: maven

Parent module containing
 - module1
 - module2 and
 - assembler

In the module 1 and module 2 I use maven assembler plugin and generate an artifact along with shell script and place it inside a target/artifact folder

What I want is to copy this target/artifact folders of module1 and module2 and put these artifact folders inside the target folder of assembler.
what is the maven plugin I should use?

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: I assume your assembler module is a separate module? If not make one and configure the maven-assembly-plugin which can create a file with the content you like.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, the assembler is a separate module. In this case how will wait for the module1 to be built and assembled and the copy them to the assembler?

Comment: Define the dependencies in your assembler module so the order is automatically done by Maven. You should not copy them ...let maven-assembly-plugin configuration do this...

Comment: ok. I did a small change, since I just needed an assembler, I built the sub modules and in the sub modules itself I added a plugin to copy the resources to it's sibling assembler.

Comment: Wrong way..make a separate module of it...add the appropriate dependencies as I already wrote..it's cleaner (separation of concerns..)..